# make js firebase files not accessible

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I'm making a website and I wanted to use firebase for user registration. In way to configurate firebase, I had to to create some js files with settings to connect to the firebase project. The issue is: if a user connects to "www.myhost.net/firebase.js", he can read all the configuration data. The question is, how do I make the js files unreachable through the links?

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking two questions here.

1. Is it safe to have my Firebase configuration public?

   - To that, I offer this question: [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)
2. Can I hide JS files from being viewed/downloaded?

   - The short answer is no. If the file is used by your webpage, it must also be publicly accessible.